# "No such file" warning on terminal launch

Tags: bash, shell, profile

I ran a source command on a file that was missing.  I forgot about it but later noticed that every time I opened a new terminal, the first line would be a warning about the missing file

```
bash: /software/intel-composer-2011u5-x86_64/bin/compilervars.sh: No such file or directory
~ $
```

How do I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Look at your `~/.bashrc` (if you use bash) or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` and look for some reference for that file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, strange errors like that are due to a file being called from one of the various initialization files your shell reads. Which one, will depend on the shell you are using and how you are launching it.

Here's a nifty function that will look through all possible `bash` init files and `grep` them for whatever you are looking for. Add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
grep_bash(){
  for f in  ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login \
        /etc/profile /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/environment; 
  do 
    [ -e $f ] && grep -H HIST $f; 
  done
}
```

You can now check which file you are calling the missing file from:

```
$ grep_bash intel-composer-2011u5-x86_64 
/home/terdon/.bashrc:source /software/intel-composer-2011u5-x86_64/bin/compilervars.sh
```